# pagination button is not working in gridview Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Pagination button is not working in gridview Yii2. If I click on page 2 button its moving to other page with URL (http://localhost/testyii/frontend/web/products/view?page=2&per-page=3) and its showing error (404 Not found URL was not found on this server). What code I have missed here.
Here is my controller:-

```
public function actionView()
    {
        $WmProducts = WmProducts::find();
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider ([
            'query' =>$WmProducts,
            'pagination' => ['pageSize'=>3],  
            ]);
        return $this->render('view', [
            'dataProvider' =>$dataProvider]);                     
    }
```

Here is view page:-

```
<?php
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use app\models\Client;
?>
<?php
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        'id',
         [
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'format' => 'text'
         ],

         [
            'attribute' => 'wholesale_price',
            'format' => 'text'
         ],
         [
            'attribute' => 'is_retail',
            'format' => 'text'
         ],
         [
            'attribute' => 'distributor_price',
            'format' => 'Text'
         ]

        ]
]);
?>
```

How to resolve it. And what I have missed in the view page.

Comment: sir  .  please give me any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

It seems You have modified the pagination component in some way if it is sending you to `/view...` instead of `/index...` URL. Are you using this GridView inside a `view.php` file? If yes, the pagination will assume that one as the base URL and you should specify which is the correct URL to use.